# Tensorboard embedding visualisation characters in Keras R (missing batch_input_shape argument)

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am using the following code for a LSTM on character basis:
https://github.com/rstudio/keras/blob/master/vignettes/examples/lstm_text_generation.R

Now the Idea is to visualize the chars in embedding in Tensorboard(It is slightly different then in Python).

I have changed the model definition to:

```
model %>%
  layer_embedding(input_dim = length(chars) + 1 , output_dim = 32, input_length = maxlen)%>%
  layer_lstm(128, input_shape = c(maxlen, length(chars))) %>%
  layer_dense(length(chars)) %>%
  layer_activation("softmax")
```

I am missing here the `batch_input_shape` argument from the same function but in Python because without it I have an dimension problem. I can use a `batch_size` argument but after running it I get this Error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_2_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (200284, 40, 57)
```

But maybe I just have an understanding problem. Thanks for every hint!